# authenticate MVC4 mobile web application with mobile azure service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

How to authenticate MVC4 mobile web application with  mobile azure service?

I would like to authenticate the Live Id from  MVC app, and I would like to use mobile azure service as the back end, so that it can share same service with our windows 8 apps.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Azure Mobile Services (a.k.a. [ZUMO](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/08/28/announcing-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx)) is only supported for Windows 8 however you sure can use it with other applications as well and mostly WebAPI is the best option to tie with your MVC application mainly while using Web API as a proxy.

You can use the the article [Using Azure Mobile Services in your web apps through ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/using-azure-mobile-services-in-your-web-apps-through-asp-net-web-api/), in your MVC4 application to authenticate your application with Mobile Azure Services.

Comment: In the above article Authentication is done with the application key, but I would like to use the Live ID for the user to login in MVC web app, same as windows 8 app. I am looking how to login with my live ID in the web app and authenticate the Live ID in mobile service, in mobile service table setting can set the security to use the logged in user..